# Software to change c++ naming conventions / Advanced batch renaming

Tags: gratis, c++, refactoring

I am looking for a free software that I could use to do batch renaming of class members in c++.

It doesn't have to be perfect, just handle most simple cases.
It is enough if it can identify class members and do a simple regex replace.(From `CamelCase` to `mCamelCase`)

It can be any tool that supports windows or a visual studio add-on.

Came from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457223/how-to-change-naming-convention-from-camelcase-to-mcamelcase)

Comment: "it doesn't have to be perfect, just identify (definitions and accesses) of class members"?   This pretty much requires perfection; if it gets it wrong, it renames accesses to other scopes, etc.   And you'll need to be able to designate a class member definition in a specific scope as the target of the renaming.

Comment: @IraBaxter I mean It doesn't have to handle external accesses to the class. When a member is public and accessed from a derived or something like that. Its enough if if modifies the class definition and class member function definitions. I am thinking of writing such a tool myself...

Comment: Good luck.  C++ will likely destroy you.

Comment: @IraBaxter Challenge accepted.